# Get deployed contract details from Private network in all connected Peers

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, private-blockchain

I have created one Ethereum private network and added two nodes inside that n/w.

I have migrate one contract using truffle in that n/w from one node.

Now I want to access that contract inside another node then how can we get it?

Is there any way to get deployed contract details from all the nodes?

Answer (score -1):

you just need contract's abi and contract address to access the contract.